# Chart not updating after data change in react chartjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, react-chartjs

I made a line chart with react chartjs. The chart is working perfectly fine but when I try to update the chart, it didn't get updated. Although I am able to change the data of the chart. Please help.
I try to update the chart on the legend click. I go through some tutorials and see like update function will help me. But when I try the update function with my line, it shows an error with 'undefined update function'.

```
import React from 'react';

import {Line} from 'react-chartjs-2';


const checkinsData={
    labels:['4 P.M','5 P.M','6 P.M','7 P.M','8 P.M','9 P.M','10 P.M','11 P.M','12 A.M','1 A.M','2 A.M','3 A.M','4 A.M'],
    datasets:[
        {
        label:"Day",
        backgroundColor:"blue",
        borderColor:'#333',
        borderWidth:2,
        lineTension:0.1,
        fill:true,
        data:[4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4]

        }


    ]
}



class CheckinGraph extends React.Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        this.state={

        }
    }

    legendClick=function() {
        console.log("Legend click"+ checkinsData.labels);
        checkinsData.datasets.data=[100,120,200,25,56,78,80,90,70,100];
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div className="col-md-12  default-shadow bg-white pd-30-0 border-radius-10 align-center">
            <Line
            redraw
        data={checkinsData}
        options={
            {
                title:{
                    text:'Total Check-ins',
                    fontSize:20,
                    display:true
                },
                legend:{
                    display:true,
                    position:'top',
                    onClick:this.legendClick
                }
            }
        }
        />
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default CheckinGraph;
```

Comment: Are you getting `Legend click` in console means is the function call made on `onClick`?

Comment: yes, I am getting data in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your chart will update/re-render when your component will get new props or state will be updated. Since your chart data that you are updating it not in state of the component, so component don't know about the change and it is not re-rendering your chart. You need to tell the component that something has changed and now time to re-render. This can be achieved by:
1. adding your data in state and then updating the data on click but in a right way (without mutating the state)
2. Added a random key in state and update the state key after updating the non-state data

```js
state = { key: Date.now() }


legendClick=function() {
        console.log("Legend click"+ checkinsData.labels);
        checkinsData.datasets[0].data=[100,120,200,25,56,78,80,90,70,100];
        this.setState({ key: Date.now() });
    }
```